# How do I unbind a library reference in F# interactive

Tags: f#, interactive

In VS 2010 I reference several libraries using #r

Once I run an interactive session these libraries get bound.  As a consequence I cannot rebuild my library because the system complains these libraries are currently used.

How do I unbind them in case I want to update the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible thing to try is the 'Reset Session' option in the FSI tool window.  (I haven't tried this myself to see if it works.)